# Dynamic Search multiple terms in linqtosql

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to do the following, If a user the enters the term "IP Address Text" into my search box then I want the following SQL to be generated:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblComments
WHERE tblComments.Text LIKE '%IP%' OR tblComments.Text LIKE '%Address%' OR tblComments.Text LIKE '%Text%'
```

Obviously the number of words entered is going to be different each time.
I have tried a for each loop in LinqToSql adding multiple where clauses but this uses "AND" instead of "OR"

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to read up on [full text searching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) as an alternative to what you're trying to accomplish here. Searching for `'%word%'` will never perform well as the query cannot use an index.

Comment: Thanks, I've ended up going down that route now, although I've only implemented it in it's simplest form.